# How to send error response to ajax in python django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../getFormMetaData/",
        cache:false,
        data: $data,
        success: createZoomDialog,
        error:function(response){

        }
    });
```

how can I send data to ajax error handler from python django?

Comment: Just send 4xx or 5xx status code on response, js will route it into error callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can return `HttpResponse` with a 4xx error code in your view:

```
def view(request):
    return HttpResponse("error", status=404)
```